# Why is this error_handler function returning NULL?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I have a class called `Error` which when loaded will register a function called `errorHandler` using the `set_error_handler` method in PHP. However, this function will return `NULL` if the function fails to load or if PHP is using the default built-in error handler. I cannot figure out why my function is not being accepted. Does anyone have any good guesses?

```
<?php
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace Request\Configuration;

use Errors\Exception\FatalException;

class Error extends Template
{
    public static function load(): void
    {
        $result = set_error_handler('self::errorHandler', error_reporting());
        var_dump($result);
    }

    public static function errorHandler(
        int $number,
        string $message,
        string $file = null,
        int $line = null,
        array $context = null
    ) {
        throw new FatalException('PHP_ERROR: ' . $message, 0);
    }
}
```

This class when loads returns `NULL`.

Comment: Why you are not using TRY - CATCH?

Comment: All of the code is wrapped in a catch block so this exception should be caught upstream when it bubbles up. But just to be certain, I removed the exception and did a die() statement instead and it still didn't work :(

Comment: could you try replacing throw new  FatalException with throw new  Exception OR throw new Error

Comment: I could not find help in PHP manual for FatalException

Comment: @MangeshSathe Just gave that a go and still got `NULL`. Nice thought though. Also FatalException is just my extension of Exception.

Comment: When you are THROWing something then there should be CATCH, I could'nt see any thing like that, and load has void in the end...didnt understand meaning of VOID here, try debug_backtrace and see if you are getting any hint in control flow

Comment: The catch statements are outside of this class, but all the exceptions are still caught don't worry. The void return type means that the function should not return any value. This problem has been solved now though. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after much debugging and exploration I have found the reason for this. The set_error_handler() function will only return the current error handler function before the time of registering a new one. It's a strange functionality. So if you want to find out if it was successfully registered you have to call this function twice. So when this function was returning `NULL` it was because the previously registered function was PHP's built-in one so it simply returned `NULL`. Watch out for this one, it's a weird function.